# xmlhttprequest simultaneous request not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make "many" *xhr* request but it seems that every time it waits for the answer before making another request. It's like *XHR* makes a queue and always wait for the previous request to finish.

What can I do to run more simultaneous *xhr* request?

```
$('body').delegate('.download','click', function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault(); // Not related

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', "proxy.php?" + this.href, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';

        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status == 200) {              
                var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type:'audio/mp4'});

                console.log(blob.size);
                if(blob.size > 0){
                    $("<a>").attr({
                        download: name,
                        href: URL.createObjectURL(blob),
                        target: "_blank"
                    })[0].click();
                }
            }
        };  
        xhr.send();
    });
```

Comment: have you tried using web worker?

Comment: Yes and the same thing happens..Both worker are called together but the second XHR wait for the first XHR to finish

Comment: How about opening new browser windows, make the requset, use post message to  send the response and then close the windows? Just thoughts that may help.. not very familiar with the subject.

Comment: Also second thought, use more variables or an array or object to store xhr.. the variable may be still in use untill the server respondes.

Comment: have you tried it with jquery deferred?just a thought.

Comment: use when library this will be solves the case
look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429765/parallel-ajax-calls-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 11):

Not a lot.

Browsers enforce a limit on:

- The number of parallel HTTP requests to a given origin
- The number of parallel HTTP requests in total (this is a larger limit)

If you split your requests between more originals you might find your constraint raised from the first to the second of the above.

Comment: I've seen that the limit enforced by chrome should be of 6 maximum request, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Try to find something about http2, there is some [info](http://qnimate.com/post-series/http2-complete-tutorial/). Http2 protocol have better supporting of parallel requests.